# Change Metainf in my own unsigned APk

Tags: android, apk, unsigned, meta-inf

I have my own unsigned apk installed into my android tablet in customer remote location. My development is crashed and now i had setup the android studio again and get the unsigned apk. But now it is not getting installed into my tablet.

I tried to rename .apk to.zip and replaced the metainf folder with my old apk meta inf folder. then .zip to .apk is throwing parse error.

My situation is to install unsigned apk with rooting the device.

Can someone suggest a way to change metainf folder so that certificate informations remains the same.